# Is using a subdomain, or an entirely new domain linked from the original better for SEO?

Tags: seo, subdomain

I'm creating a blog for an already-popular website, and was wondering if using a subdomain is better (or the same) for SEO as using an entirely different domain but linking to it from the original website?

Comment: It depends.  What is it?  How related is it?   Do you want to be able to sell it separately at some point?

Comment: it has been said by Moz that a subfolder is a better option for SEO that a subdomain.

Comment: as mentioned, a subfolder is probably the best for seo. if you only have those 2 choices, just think about whats best / easiest / coolest / .. for the user.